# Is it possible to list which boost libraries are depended

Tags: ros, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I downloaded and installed the ROS Base from source, and I found that some package depended on `boost`.

For example, in the file `package.xml` of `rospack`, I can see the line: `<run_depend>boost</run_depend>`.

As my understanding, it means that the boost is a dependency of the package `rospack`.

I'm working on Ubuntu, I execute the command `apt install libboost-all-dev` to install the boost and it is really huge.

I'm thinking if we really need to install the whole boost. If not, is it possible to know which boost libraries are really needed? For example, if it needs `boost-filesystem`, I can simply execute `apt install libboost-filesystem-dev` to install it and it is not that big.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288874/is-it-possible-to-list-which-boost-libraries-are-depended/) by [bear234](https://answers.ros.org/users/22393/bear234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it possible to list which boost libraries are depended

For Boost specifically: no, not with any of the tools ROS provides for listing/resolving/installing dependencies. That is not a limitation of those tools, but is due to the fact that there is only a single `boost` rosdep key ([this one](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/887d657093e1302f5bfa459d662fc3b1377a06d0/rosdep/base.yaml#L268-L304)), and that maps to `libboost-all-dev` on Ubuntu. If there were rules for each part of Boost individually, then what you suggest could be supported.

One reason I can think of why that is not done is that it introduces a lot of overhead as all these rules will have to be managed, kept up to date, checked for each ROS release *and* additional OS that gets supported, etc. It might also not be possible to install separate parts of Boost on some platform+OS combinations.

And that is ignoring the fact that developers would also have to figure out which Boost functionality maps to which libraries.

---

To see which libraries are really needed, you could use `ldd`.

---

If you're concerned about the sizes of packages and want/need more control over dependencies you could consider looking at [meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0